# How do I turn off the windows gradient? [SOLVED]

Tags: themes, window-management, gtk

How do I turn off the gradient of the windows? Currently I am using the [elementary-x](https://surajmandalcell.github.io/elementary-x/) (white version) theme and the gradient on the windows makes the close, minimise and maximise buttons to look kind of "unnotable" to me.

[image: Untitled.png]

Notice that Keyboard Shortcuts and some other apps has this thing where there is no upper window space so it looks a lot better than the File Manager, for instance. I would really like to make apps to look like Keyboard Shortcuts - pure white and no gradient.

Answer (score 1):

I made it to work. In `gtk-widgets.css` and `gtk-widgets-dark.css` I added/edited a `.tilebar` element with `background-image: linear-gradient()` property. As arguments I set white color hex in white-version CSS and gray color hex in dark-version CSS. To set the unfocused window's color I used a `.tilebar:backdrop` element with the same property but with darker color.